# Hide or show options menu depending on the choice in option menu 1 or 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a setup of three select option's. Two option menu's are shown, the third will be displayed when you pick a value in option menu **NIV 2**.

The way i need it to work is when you select a value in the first option menu **NIV 1** it will change the second option menu **NIV 2** with the matching option menu. When you select an value in option menu **NIV 2** a third option menu will be displayed **NIV 3**.

**Clarification for NIV 1, 2 and 3:**

[image]

With my current code i can select any value in option menu **NIV 1**, Option menu **NIV 2** will be changed accordingly what i select in option menu **NIV 1**.

**The issue:**
When i select a value in option menu **NIV 2** option menu **NIV 3** will be displayed correctly.
However for some reason option menu **NIV 2** disappears. I am unable to find the issue at this moment.

**My current code & Live Example:**

```js
$('.selectdata').change(function() {
  var role = $(this).val();
  switchRole(role);
});

function switchRole(role) {
  var sel = $('select[data-role= ' + role + '   ]');
  sel.show();
  hideSelects(role, sel)
};

hideSelects = function(role, selected) {
  var elements = $("select").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("role") !== undefined;
  });
  var toHide = $(elements).not(selected);
  toHide.hide();
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card mt-3">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-md-1 m-t-15">Select option:</label>
      <!-- OPTIE 1 -->
      <div class="col-md-1" style="max-width: 150px;">
        <select class="selectdata form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">
          <optgroup label="Select option NIV 1">
            <option value="A1">NIV1 A</option>
            <option value="A2">NIV1 B</option>
            <option value="A3">NIV1 C</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- OPTIE 2 -->
      <div class="col-md-1" style="max-width: 150px;">
        <select data-role="A1" class="selectdata form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">
          <optgroup label="Select option NIV 2">
            <option value="B11">A 11</option>
            <option value="B12">A 12</option>
            <option value="B13">A 13</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="A2" class="selectdata form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="Select option NIV 2">
            <option value="B21">A 21</option>
            <option value="B22">A 22</option>
            <option value="B23">A 23</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="A3" class="selectdata form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="Select option NIV 2">
            <option value="B31">A 31</option>
            <option value="B32">A 32</option>
            <option value="B33">A 33</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- OPTIE 3 -->
      <div class="col-md-1" style="max-width: 150px;">
        <select data-role="B11" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 A1 - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 A1 - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 A1 - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B12" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 B - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 B - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 B - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B13" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 C - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 C - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 C - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B21" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 A - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 A - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 A - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B22" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 B - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 B - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 B - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B23" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 C - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 C - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 C - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B31" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 A - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 A - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 A - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B32" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 B - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 B - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 B - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B33" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 C - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 C - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 C - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `hideSelects()` functions. It hides all selects that aren't specifically of the value of the new select as determined by the `switchRole()` function.

Supposedly, you only want to hide the selects that are *siblings* of the current select. Luckily, jQuery makes that very easy. In the snippet below I replaced:

```
var elements = $("select").filter(function() {
```

with

```
var elements = $(selected).siblings().filter(function() {
```

And it appears to work as expected. This is assuming that it is indeed the sibling selects you want hidden, and that they will always be siblings in your html. Hope that helps!

```js
$('.selectdata').change(function() {
  var role = $(this).val();
  switchRole(role);
});

function switchRole(role) {
  var sel = $('select[data-role= ' + role + '   ]');
  sel.show();
  hideSelects(role, sel)
};

hideSelects = function(role, selected) {
  var elements = $(selected).siblings().filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("role") !== undefined;
  });
  var toHide = $(elements).not(selected);
  toHide.hide();
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card mt-3">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-md-1 m-t-15">Select option:</label>
      <!-- OPTIE 1 -->
      <div class="col-md-1" style="max-width: 150px;">
        <select class="selectdata form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">
          <optgroup label="Select option NIV 1">
            <option value="A1">NIV1 A</option>
            <option value="A2">NIV1 B</option>
            <option value="A3">NIV1 C</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- OPTIE 2 -->
      <div class="col-md-1" style="max-width: 150px;">
        <select data-role="A1" class="selectdata form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">
          <optgroup label="Select option NIV 2">
            <option value="B11">A 11</option>
            <option value="B12">A 12</option>
            <option value="B13">A 13</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="A2" class="selectdata form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="Select option NIV 2">
            <option value="B21">A 21</option>
            <option value="B22">A 22</option>
            <option value="B23">A 23</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="A3" class="selectdata form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="Select option NIV 2">
            <option value="B31">A 31</option>
            <option value="B32">A 32</option>
            <option value="B33">A 33</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- OPTIE 3 -->
      <div class="col-md-1" style="max-width: 150px;">
        <select data-role="B11" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 A1 - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 A1 - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 A1 - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B12" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 B - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 B - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 B - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B13" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 C - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 C - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 C - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B21" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 A - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 A - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 A - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B22" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 B - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 B - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 B - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B23" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 C - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 C - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 C - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B31" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 A - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 A - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 A - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B32" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 B - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 B - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 B - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select data-role="B33" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px; display: none;">
          <optgroup label="OPTION NIV 3">
            <option value="1">NIV3 C - 1</option>
            <option value="2">NIV3 C - 2</option>
            <option value="3">NIV3 C - 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! searching the whole day for the solution and you fix it in a few minutes :D